# How do I fetch any info about user that modified ckrecord?

Tags: ios, swift, cloudkit

All I do is:

```
if let id = record.lastModifiedUserRecordID {
    publicDatabase.fetch(withRecordID: id) { record, error in 
        print(record)
    }
}
```

This is result of output:

```
public record: Optional(
{
    creatorUserRecordID -> 
    lastModifiedUserRecordID -> 
    creationDate -> 2018-09-09 06:23:10 +0000
    modificationDate -> 2018-09-09 06:23:10 +0000
})
```

How to retrieve any email, first name, phone number, whatever.

Answer (score 0):

I'm fairly certain that this information isn't available out-of-the-box.

You would have to create your own `lastUpdatedByUser` field on your `CKRecord` and save that information with your app when a user makes a change.

You might be able to make `lastUpdatedByUser` a `CKReference` to a `User` record type so that you get all the `user` object's details.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible, but a little indirect:

1. get the user's recordID from record.lastModifiedUserRecordID
2. get the record's share reference from record.share
3. fetch the share's record
4. Determine which of the share's participants has that recordID
5. Extract the emailAddress/phoneNumber from the participant's userIdentity.lookupInfo